How to Track a Transaction from LWC to Apex and Back Using Nebula Logger, Maintaining Logs in Order?
I am trying to log some details using Nebula Logger in Salesforce to track transactions from LWC to Apex and back to LWC. I have successfully captured detailed logs in Apex, including logs before and after external callouts, with a unique transaction ID for each request.
However, I want to initiate logging in LWC, maintain the transaction ID across both LWC and Apex, and then log the final result back in LWC after the response is received. The goal is to ensure that all the logs (from LWC, through Apex, and back to LWC) are recorded in order and tied to the same transaction.
Here’s what I need to achieve:

Log when the user clicks a button in LWC (transaction start).
Pass the transaction ID from LWC to Apex and continue logging within Apex (logs for the callout and success/error).
Log the response back in LWC (transaction end).
Ensure that the transaction ID remains consistent across LWC and Apex, and all logs are associated with the same transaction, preserving the order of events.

Logger Class:
    public with sharing class TransactionLogger {
        
        public static String logTransactionStart(String transactionName) {
            DateTime startTime = DateTime.now();
            String transactionId = generateTransactionId();
            
            // Nebula Logger usage to log the start
            Logger logger = Logger.fatal('Transaction Started: ' + transactionName)
                                  .setStartTime(startTime)
                                  .setTransactionId(transactionId)
                                  .saveLog();
                                  
            return transactionId;
        }
    
        public static void logTransactionSuccess(String transactionName, String transactionId, DateTime startTime, String details) {
            // Nebula Logger usage to log success
            Logger.info('Transaction Succeeded: ' + transactionName)
                   .setTransactionId(transactionId)
                   .setEndTime(DateTime.now())
                   .saveLog();
        }
    
        public static void logTransactionError(String transactionName, String transactionId, DateTime startTime, Exception ex) {
            // Nebula Logger usage to log errors
            Logger.error('Transaction Failed: ' + transactionName)
                   .setTransactionId(transactionId)
                   .setEndTime(DateTime.now())
                   .saveLog();
        }
    
        public static void logTransactionEnd(String transactionName, String transactionId, DateTime startTime) {
            // Nebula Logger usage to log the end of a transaction
            Logger.fatal('Transaction Ended: ' + transactionName)
                  .setTransactionId(transactionId)
                  .setEndTime(DateTime.now())
                  .saveLog();
        }
        
        private static String generateTransactionId() {
            // Generate a unique transaction ID (you can use UUID or other logic)
            return String.valueOf(Crypto.getRandomInteger());
        }
    }

Apex Class:
public with sharing class MyServiceCallout {

    public void makeCalloutAndLogTransaction(String transactionId) {
        // Initialize variables for transaction logging
        String transactionName = 'My Service Callout';
        DateTime startTime;

        try {
            // Log transaction start in Apex
            startTime = DateTime.now();
            TransactionLogger.logTransactionStart(transactionName, transactionId);

            // Make the callout (example using HTTP callout)
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint('https://example.com/api');
            req.setMethod('GET');

            Http http = new Http();
            HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

            // Check for success response
            if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                // Log success and capture additional details
                String additionalDetails = 'Received status code: ' + res.getStatusCode();
                TransactionLogger.logTransactionSuccess(transactionName, transactionId, startTime, additionalDetails);
            } else {
                // Handle failure case by logging an error
                throw new CalloutException('Callout failed with status code: ' + res.getStatusCode());
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Log transaction error if exception occurs
            TransactionLogger.logTransactionError(transactionName, transactionId, startTime, ex);
            throw ex;  // Rethrow exception if necessary
        } finally {
            // Ensure transaction end is logged
            TransactionLogger.logTransactionEnd(transactionName, transactionId, startTime);
        }
    }
}


This should go to https://github.com/jongpie/NebulaLogger/discussions or https://github.com/jongpie/NebulaLogger/issues
